# Syntax Highlight in structured text editor (JSP) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to edit my color options for syntax highlighting in structured text editor in Eclipse like I can do for Java Source Code? The maximum I could do was change the font...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What kind of syntax are you trying to highlight in regular text?

Comment: I dont understand your question...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is diferent levels of options. To edit syntax highlighting of jsp files, for example, you must access Preferences -> Web > JSP -> Editor and them syntax highlighting.